# SQLite: Escape quotes in Titanium (Javascript)

Tags: string, mobile, escaping, titanium, quotes

I'm using Titanium as a development tool and I would like to insert a string to an SQLite database.

The string contains double quotes ("), so each time it gives an error.

How can I escape the quotes in the string so I can insert the string to the database?

Thanks in advance!

Tjellekes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try this

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO schedule(NOTE) VALUES(?), "\" i am in quotes \"");
```

Comment: I have done it by using the function Replace(\"\g,"\"\""), which works now

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably prefer escape() and unescape() javascript methods wich are much more generics and safe.
It works like a charm with Titanium.